# DB2 Grant add,update,delete to user

Tags: db2

I need to grant the permissions add, update and delete to a user called "test" in a database which I'm connected to.

What would be the syntax? I've tried:

```
db2 grant add, update, delete on database to test
```

Without luck.

I'm using DB2 10 in AIX (command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the kind of permissions you can grant in a database and its objects.

I suppose "add" is insert, but that is granted over a table, not a database. The same for update and delete.

You can give permission to yourself, only if you have a supperior authority, such as sysadm, dbadm or secadm (depends on the DB2 version, and security configured).

For example:

```
db2 grant insert, update, delete on table db2inst1.emp to user test
```

To grant all DML permission on table emp in schema db2inst1

If you want to grant that to all tables, you should generate the grant sentences:

```
db2 -x +o -z commands.sql "select 'grant insert, update, delete on table ' || trim(tabschema) || '.' || trim(tabname) || ' to user test;' from syscat.tables where type = 'T'" >
db2 -tvf commands.sql
```

First command generated dinamycally all grants just by accesing the catalog. The second one, is the execution of the output of the first command.

You could eventually execute both commands in one line via a pipe, but there is a Unix limit that blocks the output.

```
db2 -x "select 'grant inser... ... pe = 'T'" | db2 +p -tv
```

- Grant info - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0005804.html
- db2 +p explanation - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0010412.html http://angocadb2.blogspot.fr/2011/12/ejecutar-la-salida-de-un-query-en-clp.html